# Spring integration: How to implement a JDBCOutboundGateway in the middle of a MessageChain?

Tags: spring-integration

This appears, to me, to be a simple problem that is probably replicated all over the place. A very basic application of the MessageHandlerChain, probably using nothing more than out of the box functionality.

Conceptually, what I need is this:

```
(1) Polled JDBC reader (sets parameters for integration pass)
    |
    V
(2) JDBC Reader (uses input from (1) to fetch data to feed through channel
    |
    V
(3) JDBC writer (writes data fetched by (2) to target)
    |
    V
(4) JDBC writer (writes additional data from the original parameters fetched in (1))
```

What I think I need is

```
Flow:
From: JdbcPollingChannelAdapter (setup adapter)
Handler: messageHandlerChain
    Handlers (
       JdbcPollingChannelAdapter (inbound adapter)
       JdbcOutboundGateway (outbound adapter)
       JdbcOutboundGateway (cleanup gateway)
    )
```

The JdbcPollingChannelAdapter does not implement the MessageHandler API, so I am at a loss how to read the actual data based on the setup step.

Since the JdbcOutboundGateway does not implement the MessageProducer API, I am at a bit of a loss as to what I need to use for the outbound adapter.

Are there OOB classes I should be using? Or do I need to somehow wrap the two adapters in BridgeHandlers to make this work?

Thanks in advance

---

**EDIT (2)**
Additional configuration problem

The setup adapter is pulling a single row back with two timestamp columns. They are being processed correctly by the "enrich headers" piece.

However, when the inbound adapter is executing, the framework is passing in java.lang.Object as parameters. Not String, not Timestamp, but an actual java.lang.Object as in `new Object ()`.

It is passing the correct number of objects, but the content and datatypes are lost. Am I correct that the ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory needs to be configured?

Message:

`GenericMessage [payload=[{startTime=2020-11-18 18:01:34.90944, endTime=2020-11-18 18:01:34.90944}], headers={startTime=2020-11-18 18:01:34.90944, id=835edf42-6f69-226a-18f4-ade030c16618, timestamp=1605897225384}]`

SQL in the JdbcOutboundGateway:

```
Select t.*, w.operation as "ops" from ADDRESS t
Inner join TT_ADDRESS w 
  on (t.ADDRESSID = w.ADDRESSID)
  And (w.LASTUPDATESTAMP >= :payload.from[0].get("startTime") and w.LASTUPDATESTAMP <= :payload.from[0].get("endTime") )
```

---

**Edit:** added solution java DSL configuration

```
private JdbcPollingChannelAdapter setupAdapter; // select only
private JdbcOutboundGateway inboundAdapter; // select only
private JdbcOutboundGateway insertUpdateAdapter; // update only
private JdbcOutboundGateway deleteAdapter; // update only
private JdbcMessageHandler cleanupAdapter; // update only

        setFlow(IntegrationFlows
            .from(setupAdapter, c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).maxMessagesPerPoll(1)))
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression("ALC_startTime", "payload.from[0].get(\"ALC_startTime\")")
                    .headerExpression("ALC_endTime", "payload.from[0].get(\"ALC_endTime\")"))
            .handle(inboundAdapter)
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression("ALC_operation", "payload.from[0].get(\"ALC_operation\")"))
            .handle(insertUpdateAdapter)
            .handle(deleteAdapter)
            .handle(cleanupAdapter)
            .get());

flowContext.registration(flow).id(this.getId().toString()).register();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to carry the original arguments down to the last gateway in your flow, you need to store those arguments in the headers since after every step the payload of reply message is going to be different and you won't have original setup data over there any more. That's first.

Second: if you deal with `IntegrationFlow` and Java DSL, you don't need to worry about `messageHandlerChain` since conceptually the `IntegrationFlow` is a chain by itself but much more advance.

I'm not sure why you need to use a `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` to request data on demand according incoming message from the source in the beginning of your flow.

You definitely still need to use a `JdbcOutboundGateway` for just `SELECT` mode. The `updateQuery` is optional, so that gateway is just going to perform `SELECT` and return a data for you in a payload of the reply message.

If you two next steps are just "write" and you don't care about the result, you probably can just take a look into a `PublishSubscribeChannel` and two `JdbcMessageHandler` as subscribers to it. Without a provided `Executor` for the `PublishSubscribeChannel` they are going to be executed one-by-one.

Comment: This looks like what I am looking for.

If I understand, this is what you are saying: Integrationflow ( JdbcPollingChannelAdapter  -> JdbcOutboundGateway (select mode only)  -> JdbcMessageHandler -> JdbcMessageHandler )

Comment: Something like the code snip I just added to the question above

Comment: It's hard to read the code from the comments, but if your `outboundAdapter` is a `JdbcOutboundGateway`, then it is going to work. You probably don't need those channels in between: the `IntegrationFlow` adds them for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks.  I will test shortly

Comment: I have made the necessary changes and tested. The flow does not launch.  I have tested by putting a breakpoint at JdbcPollingChannelAdapter.doPoll(), which should be the very first place the chain is invoked, but it never launches.

Comment: The `IntegrationFlow` must be registered in the application context as a bean. If it doesn’t flow and you don’t see any errors, then it is indeed you are missing that bean part

Comment: When the inbound adapter (JdbcOutboundGateway in select only mode) is executing, the framework is passing in java.lang.Object as parameters. See question edits above.

Is the correct way to resolve this through the replySqlParameterSourceFactory? How do you properly configure this?

Comment: Well, it is an `ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory` by default. And the `requestMessage` is a root object for that. You need to be sure that your `SELECT` with params satisfies the root object of the evaluation context. It must be something like `:payload.foo`, where `foo` is a getter on the POJO inside the request message payload.

Comment: so "select x from y where z=:payload.foo" ?

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean, but since I don't know what is your payload, I can't advice the proper expression.

Comment: This is close enough for now. While I'd love to get you to write the whole thing for me, I need to learn my way through it as well   :D  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I've given up on the SPEL. Is there an easy way to test SPEL expressions without going trial and error?

I have added message and SQL details to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what is `from[0]`, but did you try like this `:payload..startTime`? The way to test expression is a `SpelExpressionParser.parseExpression()` and then `Expression.getValue(@Nullable Object rootObject)`. The `rootObject` must be exactly a `Message` you have in your flow. Well, maybe without headers... You may also think about a `splitter()` before your `.handle(inboundAdapter)`. Or see if `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter.setMaxRows(1)` is enough for you to avoid dealing with collections.